# Use a hostname with Flask rather than an ip-address

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask server in an embedded device (running linux) which has both wifi and wired ethernet ports. I access the flask server via the wifi on 192.168.101.1 and from the wired port on 10.10.10.156.

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443, debug=False, ssl_context=context)
```

E.g. https://192.168.101.1/route1

I want to use a hostname rather than an ip-address.

E.g. https://my.device/route1

How would I set this up? I have read about the flask run '** options' parameter but cant figure it out and I have also set this up in the /etc/hosts file but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up by configuring the `hosts` file on each of your client devices, if possible. For example, on a linux machine you might have in your `/etc/hosts` file:

`192.168.101.1  my.device`

This will cause the client to resolve my.device to the IP address 192.168.101.1.